# How to update bourbon neat files in my site

Tags: updates, bourbon, neat

I installed Neat prior to the most recent gem update to 1.7.1. Now I'd like to update the files in my site install, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

```
gem list
```

indicates

```
neat (1.7.1)
```

I tried

```
neat install
```

in my sass directory, but I get the message

```
Neat files already installed, doing nothing.
```

I'm not sure how to check what version I have installed, but the _outer-container.scss file for one is clearly a previous version when compared against the git repo.  The [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat) doesn't seem to cover precisely how to update my site files. I feel like this might be a really basic thing, I'm just not sure what to do outside manually copying the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `neat install`, try `neat update`.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought to try that.